# Rails 3 - Passing parameters to show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model `College` that has a `show` action in its controller. 
So I can access /colleges/1 and the view will display info about college with id 1.
In that view, I have some tabs 'students', 'contests', etc. 
My intent is that when user clicks on 'students', the view shows students in that college.
And when user clicks on 'contests', the view shows contests scheduled in that college.

What is the best way to support this ? 
1. Custom actions such as /colleges/1/showstudents and /colleges/1/showcontests ?
2. Show action with parameters, such as /colleges/1/show?type=students, ?type=contests ?

I was thinking #2, and in the view I can do `<% if params[:type] <=> "contests" .. %>`
but how do I put a link in the tab for 'contests' ?

It didn't seem right.

So what is the best practice for this scenario ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think that you should have a college_controller.rb and then in there just 
have a students method which will evaluate a college parameter and display students from that college ie.

```
def students
  college = College.find(params[:college_id])
  @students = college.students
end
```

Comment: I could do that, but how do I map URL /colleges/1/students to the new action 'students' ?

Comment: But my question was more like - Can I accomplish this by just reusing the 'show' action instead of adding a new action (which calls for a new view, and ends up in code duplication)

Comment: The new action would map like this /colleges/students?college=1. You could use the show action again, but your view will just get more logic added which is not where logic type code should go. It might be something like def show; @students = College.find(params[:college_id]) if params[:college_id]; end

Comment: Good job earl! One thing though, the params[:college_id] is dependent on your routes file, the default value being just params[:id] unless otherwise specified.